# How to find partial derivatives of the Beta Function?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, special-functions, multivariable-calculus

I was reading the book *(Almost) Impossible Integrals, Sums and Series*. The author used a method involving taking partial derivatives of the Beta Function to solve some integrals.
$$B(x,y)=\int_0^1u^{x-1}(1-u)^{y-1}du$$
Substituting $t=1-2u$, we get
$$2^{x+y-1}B(x,y)=\int_{-1}^1(1-t)^{x-1}(1+t)^{y-1}dt$$
Differentiating, we get
$$\dfrac{\partial^4}{\partial x^2\partial y^2}\left(2^{x+y-1}B(x,y)\right)=\int_{-1}^1(1-t)^{x-1}\log^2(1-t)(1+t)^{y-1}\log^2(1+t)dt\tag{1}$$
Taking the limits $x\to1$ and $y\to1$ on both sides,
$$\lim_{x\to1, y\to1}\dfrac{\partial^4}{\partial x^2\partial y^2}\left(2^{x+y-1}B(x,y)\right)=\int_{-1}^1\log^2(1-t)\log^2(1+t)dt$$
$$\int_{-1}^1\log^2(1-t)\log^2(1+t)dt=\dfrac{1}{4}\lim_{x\to1, y\to1}\dfrac{\partial^4}{\partial x^2\partial y^2}\left(2^{x+y}B(x,y)\right)$$
Next, the author says to calculate the RHS using Mathematica, to obtain
$$\int_{-1}^1\log^2(1-t)\log^2(1+t)dt=24−8\zeta(2)−8\zeta(3)−\zeta(4)+8\log(2)\zeta(2)-4\log^2(2)\zeta(2)+8\log(2)\zeta(3)−24\log(2)+12\log^2(2)-4\log^3(2)+\log^4(2)$$
How is the calculation of the step, the author tells us to perform by Mathematica, actually performed?

---

I already posted this on [Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4792106/how-to-find-partial-derivatives-of-the-beta-function), but didn't get any satisfactory response for 2 weeks, so I've crossposted it here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The input you need to calculate second derivatives of Beta functions is
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}B(x,y)=\bigl[\psi ^{(0)}(x)-\psi ^{(0)}(x+y)\bigr] B(x,y),$$
$$\frac{\partial^n}{\partial x^n}\psi ^{(0)}(x)=\psi ^{(n)}(x),$$
and then you need the limiting values at $(x,y)=(1,1)$,
$$B(1,1)=1,\;\;\psi ^{(0)}(1)=-\gamma_{\rm{Euler}},\;\;\psi ^{(0)}(2)=1-\gamma_{\rm{Euler}},\;\;\psi ^{(1)}(1)=\pi^2/6,$$
$$\qquad\psi ^{(1)}(2)=\pi^2/6-1,\;\;\psi ^{(2)}(2)=2-2 \zeta (3),\;\;\psi ^{(3)}(2)=\pi ^4/15-6.$$
The rest is algebra.